# terraform import an existing AWS resource to a module

Tags: amazon-web-services, import, terraform, terraform-modules

I have got an AWS account that already has ECR and IAM ready. I am now creating a new environment using terraform modules. But I could not find a way to import the existing IAM and ECR resources to my modules. When I run the command `terraform import aws_ecr_repository.c2m_an c2m_an`, I am getting an error as

```
Error: resource address "aws_ecr_repository.c2m_cs" does not exist in the configuration.

Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module. For example:

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "c2m_cs" {
  # (resource arguments)
}
```

My ECR module definition is as follows:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "c2m_cs" {
  name = var.c2m_cs#"c2m_cs"
}

output "c2m_cs" {
  value = "terraform import aws_ecr_repository.c2m_cs c2m_cs"
}
```

And in my `main.tf` file withtin my environment folder, I have module definition as follows:

```
module "ecr" {
  source = "../modules/ecr"
  c2m_cs = module.ecr.c2m_cs
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To correct way to import a resource into the module is exemplified in [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/import.html#example-import-into-module):

```
terraform import module.foo.aws_instance.bar i-abcd1234
```

Thus in your case it would be:

```
terraform import module.aws_ecr_repository.c2m_an c2m_an
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin. May be I can skip <id-of-ecr-repo> as that is not needed for ECR import. And yes it worked :)

Comment: From the example you mentioned in the docs, you're missing the "foo" part, which would be the module name. This answer is not working for me.